# Colortbl messing up array in htlatex

Tags: amsmath, tex4ht, htlatex, colortbl

When compiling the following example with htlatex:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[\begin{array}{|l|c|} \hline 1 & 2\\ \end{array}\]
\end{document}
```

with the following configuration file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml,mathml,-css,NoFonts,fn-in}
\Configure{VERSION}{}
\Configure{DOCTYPE}{\HCode{<!DOCTYPE html>\Hnewline}}
\Configure{HTML}{\HCode{<html>\Hnewline}}{\HCode{\Hnewline</html>}}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

it generates a html document containing the following MathML code for the `array`:

```
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" display="block" >
  <mrow>
    <mtable  align="axis" style="border-right:solid 1px black;border-left:solid 1px black;" equalrows="false" columnlines="solid" equalcolumns="false" class="array">
      <tr class="hline">
        <td><hr /></td>
        <td><hr /></td>
      </tr>
      <mtr>
        <mtd class="array"  columnalign="left">
          <mn>1</mn>
          ...
```

The above MathML code is invalid because `tr` is not allowed in MathML. 
When commenting out `\usepackage{colortbl}` the following good output is generated:

```
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" display="block" >
  <mrow>
    <mtable  align="axis" style="border-right:solid 1px black;border-left:solid 1px black;" equalrows="false" columnlines="solid" equalcolumns="false" class="array">
      <mtr class="hline">
        <mtd> <mo> ̲ </mo> </mtd>
        <mtd> <mo> ̲ </mo> </mtd>
      </mtr>
      <mtr>
        <mtd class="array"  columnalign="left">
          <mn>1</mn>
          ...
```

Is there something I can put in the configuration file which stops colortbl breaking arrays which are not using colortbl?

Furthermore in my latex file there are colored array, for example:

```
\[\begin{array}{|l|c|} \hline \cellcolor[gray]{.8} 1 & 2\\ \end{array}\]
```

Is there a way to make them generate valid html with the above configuration (`xhtml,mathml,-css`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that this issue is caused by configuration for `array` package, it redefines the configuration for horizontal line in table, but it doesn't take into account `MathML`. I will fix this issue in the `tex4ht` sources, so it should show in TeXLive soon. In the meantime, you can try the following configuration file:

```
%\Preamble{xhtml,mathml,-css,NoFonts,fn-in}
\Preamble{xhtml,mathml,NoFonts,fn-in}
\Configure{VERSION}{}
\Configure{DOCTYPE}{\HCode{<!DOCTYPE html>\Hnewline}}
\Configure{HTML}{\HCode{<html>\Hnewline}}{\HCode{\Hnewline</html>}}
\catcode`\:=11
   \Configure{putHBorder}{
  \bgroup \ifmathml
\Configure{HBorder}
   {<\:MM tr\Hnewline
       \ifmathml \expandafter\mml:class\else class\fi="hline">}
   {\ifmathml<\a:mathml mtd><mo> \string&\#x0332; </mo></\a:mathml mtd>
\else
            <td><hr\xml:empty></td>\fi}
   {</\:MM tr>}
   {<\:MM tr\Hnewline
       \ifmathml \expandafter\mml:class\else class\fi ="cline">}
   {<\:MM td></\:MM td>}
   {\ifmathml<\a:mathml mtd><mo> \string&\#x0332; </mo></\a:mathml mtd>
\else
            <td><hr\xml:empty></td>\fi}
   {</\:MM tr>}
   {<\:MM tr\Hnewline
         \ifmathml \expandafter\mml:class\else  class\fi="vspace"
         style="font-size:\HBorderspace">}
   {<\:MM td\Hnewline>\ifmathml\else\string&\#x00A0;\fi
      </\:MM td>}
   {</\:MM tr>}
   \fi\HCode{\HBorder}\egroup}
\catcode`\:=12
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

I've added configuration for `addHBorder`, which is used for `hline` handling. It configures `HBorder` configuration when it is used in the MathML mode. This configuration was copy-pasted from `tex4ht` sources.
Note that it can't work properly without CSS, which is disabled in your configuration file. I've enabled it in order to show expected results.

For this sample file:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\definecolor{maroon}{cmyk}{0,0.87,0.68,0.32}

\begin{document}
\[\begin{array}{|l|c|} \hline 1 & 2\\ \end{array}\]


\[
\begin{array}{|l|cr}
  left1 & center1 & right1\\
  \hline
  d & e & f
\end{array} 
\]

\begin{tabular}{l|l}
  l & l\\
  \hline
  l & l\\
\end{tabular}

\noindent\begin{tabular}{|l|c|}
  \rowcolor{maroon}
  one & two \\
  \rowcolor{maroon!50}
  three & four \\
  \rowcolor{maroon!10}
  five & six
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Your anwser for the first question works. With regard to the second question: I thought it might be possible to set the mathbackground attribute such that no additonal css file is necessary, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/MathML/Attribute